# Maintaining state in SMS based Communication

Tags: c#, asp.net, sms, session-state

we are developing a SMS based quiz competition, in that user requests to start quiz by sending sms to our server. then questions are asked by server and user replies to it. Entire application is a web project(C#). So i have to maintain state between the requests. Im looking for a SMS Session something similar to ASP.NET Session. Here SessionId is the mobno of the user. 
if user fails to respond to a question then session should be timed out... Please help me in finding a solution to this scenario...'

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you store your sessions in a database, you will need to have a background process that monitors the sessions and when a session expires you can update the session record in the database and generate the SMS message to notify the user.

The background process could be a windows service that scans the DB or depending on the back-end database you are using you could use a scheduled database task to perform the check, most server based databases like SQL Server support the concept of scheduled jobs.

Answer (score 0):

At the receiving of the first SMS from the specific number, you must start the session, by generating and storing the unique ID with response with it and also store the time of receiving the sms. After that each and every time you are getting the reply, update the time to that session id in the database.

You can check the Session timeout by checking the currently sms time and the last sms time.

This is the way i think you can maintain the session over here.

Comment: thanks for ur quick reply Bhavik. but i have to inform the user that his/her session has been timed out and score. Your solution will work only if the user send any message after timeout, ive to send it automatically when timeout occurs